# VBScript/Classic ASP find lines within csv file

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a simple script which opens a csv file then (this worked fine with 1 result) iterates through to find an "x" and "y" value, then output those values.  Problem is, with 3 different results I can only ever get it to display the final set of values.  I know this is likely a simple for each/while syntax solution but as daft as it sounds, I can never get a for each to work correctly.  The code I have currently (as everything else broke badly and left it as it originally worked):

```
dim fs,objTextFile
set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim arrStr
set objTextFile = fs.OpenTextFile("Colour.csv")

Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    arrStr = split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")
        if arrStr(0) = "x" Then
            Xval = arrStr(1)
        end if
        if arrStr(0) = "y" Then
            Yval = arrStr(1)                
        end if
Loop
response.write(Xval & "<br />")
response.write(Yval & "<br />")
objTextFile.Close
set objTextFile = Nothing
set fs = Nothing
```

And a sample from the CSV file:

```
,
,
,
Name,Measurement #1
Date,11/07/2014
Time,10:52
T_int [ms],1439
,
Lv [cd/sqm],242.2
Le [W/(sr*sqm)] (380-780nm),0.8
CCT [K],5015
DWl [nm],568.8
PE [%],12.7
,
Chrom. Coord.,
x,0.3463
y,0.3625
u',0.2081
v',0.4901
------
,
,
,
Name,Measurement #2
Date,11/07/2014
Time,10:52
T_int [ms],1439
,
Lv [cd/sqm],242.2
Le [W/(sr*sqm)] (380-780nm),0.8
CCT [K],5015
DWl [nm],568.8
PE [%],12.7
,
Chrom. Coord.,
x,0.4724
y,0.0765
u',0.2081
v',0.4901
```

It's each of the x and y values (in Chrom. Coord) I need to retrieve then place them each in their own variable.  How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these lines into your `Do` loop:

```
response.write(Xval & "<br />")
response.write(Yval & "<br />")
```

Comment: Blindingly simple .... my only excuse is that it was Friday afternoon and ready for the weekend!